# How to power a raspberry pi and brushless motor from wall outlet

Tags: power-supply

I am working on a device that uses a raspberry pi (5v and 2.5 amps) and a brushless dc motor (11.1V at .066 amps --
 http://1012007.kancart.com/item_description/431).  I want the device to plug directly into the wall.  How would I go about finding a power supply that can power both of these devices?

Comment: You left out a lot details between the gimbal motor and the wall. http://gimbal.cheesycam.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/SimpleBGC-Basecam-32-Bit-schematic-wiring-diagram-joystick-remote-brushless-motors-pitch-roll-yaw.jpg

Comment: That gimbal motor can draw up to 10 A so you are looking for a power supply of at least 120 W peak capacity. Not exactly a wall wart type solution.

Comment: But it says it can run on .066A so it should be fine still if it only has .066A right?   It may just not move as fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You require two different voltages. Your options are:

- Use a USB mains power supply for the Pi and a 12 V, 500 to 2000 mA mains power supply for the motor. That means two wall warts. Very cheap and less likelihood of the Pi getting interference from the motor.
- Use a 12 V supply and a voltage regulator to drop the voltage to the Pi. This is a bit more bother but neater on the mains side.

I'd go with the first one. You probably have a suitable PSU lying around. If it all works and you want to tidy it up then look at the second option.

---

Edit:

I took your 0.066 A motor current as being max or close to max. As pointed out in the comments, it can, for some reason, draw up to 10 A. This isn't typical wall-wart capability.

Comment: you also need a 3phase type controller for desired f to get desired RPM

Comment: Maybe. I assumed he had that.

Comment: Will it be a problem if the ground and power supply are attached to an entire different power supply as the pin that controls the motor?  Like if the grounds aren't connected will it cause problems?

Comment: I think you are into something over your head to control a gimbal motor if you dont know the logic and motor driver must use a common ground.